# Validation Error while creating partial invoice from sales order in Odoo 10

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

When am creating partial invoice (down payment), I got the below error

> The operation cannot be completed, probably due to the following:- deletion: you may be trying to delete a record while other records still reference it- creation/update: a mandatory field is not correctly set
>
> [object with reference: categ_id - categ.id]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

As far as my understanding, I think you have done some customizations in the DB, that's why this error. The error says that there is a mandatory field, but you are not supplied the value into it. The field is shown in the error message, categ_id.

Thanks